# How can I float a bunch of block-level elements such that they occupy 50% of the width including border, padding, and margin?

Tags: css

Here's a mockup of what I'm going for: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Q3aN2/

It has a wrapper container, a bunch of `<section>` elements, and then some unwanted wrapper divs to space out the content.

Is there a way of doing this that eliminates the unwanted markup? `display: table-*` perhaps?

Comment: I'm trying to stay semantic here. ALthough I agree, a table _would_ solve the problem

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data, as it appears you are doing, then a table is perfectly legal :)

Comment: That depends on whether it's for layout/design reasons, or for displaying tabular data...

Comment: It's for layout/design reasons. Sorry that my example doesn't represent that

Answer (score 0):

No, your example looks good to me. I've always used wrapper elements in the past.